# How to add UI Elements in the View for a VS Code extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to figure out how I can add UI Elements to the Activity Bar in VS Code Extensions.

For example this extension called ThunderClient. It has a button , and then tabs following it. Which again have a search box followed by list of items.
[Thunderclient Activity Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15t9C.png)

How can I achieve this type of UI. Not exactly this but i would like to have a button followed by list of items.

So far I understood Activity Bar supports only [TreeView](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/ux-guidelines/views) . Webviews are not supported in Activity Bar. So how else can this be achieved ?

I tried having a webview linked to the View container of Activity bar , but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **WebViews** in **Activity** Bar. It is documented here https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.views.

> The content of a view can be populated in two ways:
>
> - With a TreeView by providing a data provider through createTreeView API or register the data provider directly through registerTreeDataProvider API to populate data. TreeViews are ideal for showing hierarchical data and lists. Refer to the tree-view-sample.
> - With a WebviewView by registering a provider with registerWebviewViewProvider. Webview views allow rendering arbitrary HTML in the view. See the webview view sample extension for more details.

You just have to define the `type` of the view as `webview`.

```json
    "contributes": {
        "views": {
            "explorer": [
                {
                    "type": "webview",
                    ...
```

The [vscode-extension-sample](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples) repo has a sample that shows exactly this feature. Take a look at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/main/webview-view-sample

Comment: Thank you that was helpful , Unfortulately i dont have enough reputation to upvote your post. But your comment really helped me.

Comment: That’s great to hear it was helpful! And don’t worry about the upvote… no problem.